# why aren't I allowed to declare a function thats being implemented in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I made a .d.ts file with my parameter types, and the global declration of the function.
This worked fine as long as the global function was written in javascript.

When converted to typescript, i referenced the .d.ts file, to import the types.
But when compiling it complains about the function being both declared and implemented, aka `error TS2384: Overload signatures must all be ambient or non-ambient.`

1. Why can't I refer my d.ts file with the declaration? / Why aren't I allowed to declare a function thats being implemented in typescript?

In old C, it was ok to include the h-file with the declarations for the current file, and often very useful.

2. Where should i put implementation, interfaces and function delcarations, and how should i refer between them to avoid errors? (as my currentwhy to split them up in a .ts and a .d.ts file isn't correct)

Made a minifed exemple:

```
// test.d.ts
interface test_option {
    a: boolean;
}

declare function test(options: test_option): boolean;
```

```
// test.ts
/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />

function test(options: test_option): boolean {
    return !options.a;
}
```

```
// test2.ts
/// <reference path="test.d.ts" />

window.console.log(test({a: true}));
```

Comment: not sure if there is reason why you want to create d.ts and then implement it in typescript. you create d.td for javascript files. you dont need it for ts... and if you wnat to have d.ts you can still set "declaration": true. in tsconfig so compiler will create custom d.ts files for you

Answer (score 0):

This is just the way it is. You either create a definition file for a legacy JavaScript file or you implement the it in typescript. You can't create a definition file for something that is implemented in Typescript.

The solution seems simple, just move the signatures of the function to the implementation and it should be fine.

Comment: As i have a global script that is loaded on all pages, and page-specific scripts that are loaded on specific pages, I want to be able to run the global function from both files.